# Can Microsoft access the contents of my OneDrive Personal Vault?

Tags: windows, privacy, microsoft-onedrive

I found the article to be quite informative that addresses the question "Can Microsoft access my private files?" ([Can Microsoft access all private data if a user installs Windows 10?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129376/can-microsoft-access-all-private-data-if-a-user-installs-windows-10#new-answer?newreg=50fd2fbccd9c4d3ca90be4d2f44ca55a)), which includes my OneDrive files, but it didn't specifically mention the special folder called Personal Vault.  Does Microsoft have just as much capability of accessing the contents of my Personal Vault as it does all my other OneDrive files, or is Personal Vault an exception?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can unlock your Personal Vault by [SMS, Email and various other methods](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2019/06/25/onedrive-personal-vault-added-security-onedrive-additional-storage/#:%7E:text=Just%20enter%20a%20PIN%2C%20or,with%20the%20Microsoft%20Authenticator%20app.), so Microsoft's internal systems would be able to read/decrypt your data similar to how OneDrive's regular files operate. There is also no mention about losing access to files after a password reset, which would be the case if the data was encrypted with a key that Microsoft didn't control.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft manages all encryption keys and in theory can access all your content. What keeps them from doing that are operational security procedures.